# Hibernate: ERROR Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list' - two @ManyToOne relationships from one entity to the same parent entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm persisting a MySQL database with Hibernate 5.2.10[image]

The child table Game has a couple of peculiarities:

First of all it has a composite primary key made of 4 columns, namely **leagueId**, which is also a foreign key of League, **seasonId**, which is also a foreign key of Season, **roundNo**, **gameNo**

Second, two of the table's foreign keys are pointing to the same table, i.e to Club.id: **homeTeamId** and **awayTeamId**.

I'm trying to query against the Club entity, but I keep on getting the same error message.

The query:

```
List<Game> gameList = session.createQuery("FROM Game g WHERE g.id.leagueId = 1L  AND g.id.seasonId = 1L AND g.id.roundNo = 35 AND g.id.gameNo = 7")
    .getResultList();
```

which translates into this:

**Hibernate: select game0_.gameNo as gameNo1_1_, game0_.leagueId as leagueId2_1_, game0_.roundNo as roundNo3_1_, game0_.seasonId as seasonId4_1_, game0_.clubAway as clubAway5_1_, game0_.clubHome as clubHome6_1_, game0_.date as date7_1_, game0_.gameDescr as gameDesc8_1_, game0_.league as league9_1_, game0_.played as played10_1_, game0_.postponed as postpon11_1_, game0_.season as season12_1_ from game game0_ where game0_.leagueId=1 and game0_.seasonId=1 and game0_.roundNo=35 and game0_.gameNo=7**

The error:

**ERROR: Unknown column 'game0_.clubAway' in 'field list'**

I think the error might be due to those two foreign keys pointing to the same Club table, but I'm pretty lost and don't know how to solve this problem. I think my entity classes are mapped properly.

The **Game** class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    private GameId id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    private Boolean postponed;
    private Boolean played;
    private String gameDescr;

    private League league;
    private Season season;
    private Club clubHome;
    private Club clubAway;

    public Game() {
    }

    //unannotated getters and setters omitted for brevity

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="leagueId", referencedColumnName="id", table="League")
    public League getLeague() {
        return league;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="seasonId", referencedColumnName="id", table="Season")
    public Season getSeason() {
        return season;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="homeTeamId", referencedColumnName="id", table="Club")
    public Club getClubHome() {
        return clubHome;
    }   

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="awayTeamId", referencedColumnName="id", table="Club")
    public Club getClubAway() {
        return clubAway;
    }
}
```

The **GameId** class:

```
@Embeddable
public class GameId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long leagueId;
    private Long seasonId;
    private Integer roundNo;
    private Integer gameNo;

    public GameId() {
    }

    //getters and setters omitted for brevity

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // code omitted for brevity
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //code omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

The **Club** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Club")
public class Club implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String clubName;

    private League league;

    public Club() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //unannotated getters and setters omitted for brevity

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "currentLeagueId")
    public League getLeague() {
        return league;
    }
}
```

The **League** class:

```
@Entity
public class League implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String leagueName;
    private String descr;

    public League() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //unannotated getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The **Season** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="season")
public class Season implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private Integer yearBegin;
    private Integer yearEnd;
    private String descr;

    public Season(){
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //unannotated getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The tables shown here are a subset of the entire database, which consists of 7 tables, but I've tested queries against all the other 6 entities and they worked smoothly. The problem must be in the Game entity, but I've no idea what's wrong with it. Can anybody shed some light on this issue? Thank you very much in advance to all those who'll help!

Comment: Missing foreign key from club table in your game table

Comment: Actually both the getClubHome() and getClubAway() methods in the Game entity have a @ManyToOne annotation pointing to the Club entity.

Comment: Look at your ER model. You need to import as a foreign key

Comment: I can't really get what you're saying. How would you exactly fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems crazy but all I needed to do was moving the **@EmbeddedId** annotation from the field to the getter in the **Game** class.

Now the Game class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private GameId id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    private Boolean postponed;
    private Boolean played;
    private String gameDescr;

    private League league;
    private Season season;
    private Club clubHome;
    private Club clubAway;

    public Game() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public GameId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    //everything else stays the same
```